# iPhone: Unitt WebSocket Connection Issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, websocket

I'm using a library called Unitt (http://code.google.com/p/unitt/wiki/UnittWebSocketClient) to establish a connection via a web socket to a remote server.  However, I can't seem to get a connection to establish.  I've configured the Xcode project appropriately and it builds and compiles with no problems, but in the console output, I only see:

> Oops. An error occurred.
>
> Oops. It closed.

Ordinarily, the handshake request should be sending about three parameters, including username, type of connection, etc.  Here's the code I'm currently using:

```
WebSocketConnectConfig* config = [WebSocketConnectConfig configWithURLString:@"ws://myip:myport" origin:nil protocols:nil tlsSettings:nil headers:nil verifySecurityKey:YES extensions:nil ];
config.closeTimeout = 15.0;
```

Should this work, or do I need to somehow configure it with the username and other information I hope to send in the handshake?

Appreciate any input, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in any headers you want by using the "headers" parameter in your construction of the WebSocketConnectConfig. Headers explicitly specified as part of the web socket API may have properties, but any headers you desire can be specified in the headers parameter. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

If you're still having this problem, you should try [SocketRocket](https://github.com/square/SocketRocket). (disclaimer: I'm the author of it)

It supports the latest standard.